# Get informations from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a json file like this:

```
[
    {
        "countryName": "Austria",
        "countryID": "AT",
        "countryPopulation": 8451860,
        "regions":[
            {
                "regionName": "Burgenland (AT)",
                "regionID": "AT11",
                "regionPopulation": 286691 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Niederösterreich",
                "regionID": "AT12",
                "regionPopulation": 1618592
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Wien",
                "regionID": "AT13",
                "regionPopulation": 1741246
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Kärnten",
                "regionID": "AT21",
                "regionPopulation": 555473 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Steiermark",
                "regionID": "AT22",
                "regionPopulation": 1210971 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Oberösterreich",
                "regionID": "AT31",
                "regionPopulation": 1418498 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Salzburg",
                "regionID": "AT32",
                "regionPopulation": 531898 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Tirol",
                "regionID": "AT33",
                "regionPopulation": 715888  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Vorarlberg",
                "regionID": "AT34",
                "regionPopulation": 372603 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "countryName": "Belgium",
        "countryID": "BE",
        "countryPopulation": 11161642,
        "regions":[
            {
                "regionName": "Région de Bruxelles-Capitale",
                "regionID": "BE10",
                "regionPopulation": 1174624 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Antwerpen",
                "regionID": "BE21",
                "regionPopulation": 1802309  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Limburg (BE)",
                "regionID": "BE22",
                "regionPopulation": 855963 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Oost-Vlaanderen",
                "regionID": "BE23",
                "regionPopulation": 1465150  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Vlaams-Brabant",
                "regionID": "BE24",
                "regionPopulation": 1103737  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. West-Vlaanderen",
                "regionID": "BE25",
                "regionPopulation": 1177567 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Brabant Wallon",
                "regionID": "BE31",
                "regionPopulation": 389479  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Hainaut",
                "regionID": "BE32",
                "regionPopulation": 1332489 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Liège",
                "regionID": "BE33",
                "regionPopulation": 1095977
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Luxembourg (BE)",
                "regionID": "BE34",
                "regionPopulation": 278278 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Namur",
                "regionID": "BE35",
                "regionPopulation": 486069 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "countryName": "Bulgaria",
        "countryID": "BG",
        "countryPopulation": 7284552,
        "regions":[
            {
                "regionName": "Severozapaden",
                "regionID": "BG31",
                "regionPopulation": 823469 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Severen tsentralen",
                "regionID": "BG32",
                "regionPopulation": 844511 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Severoiztochen",
                "regionID": "BG33",
                "regionPopulation": 957460 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Yugoiztochen",
                "regionID": "BG34",
                "regionPopulation": 1067981 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Yugozapaden",
                "regionID": "BG41",
                "regionPopulation": 2128783 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Yuzhen tsentralen",
                "regionID": "BG42",
                "regionPopulation": 1462348 
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
```

Then I have two variables: `cs` and `rs`. At any moment only one of them is different from null.

`cs` contains the country selected by the user, `rs` contains the region selected by the user.
As said before, if `cs` is different from null, then `rs` is null and vice versa.
This is because the user can select a country from a map or select a region of a country.

My goal is to create a checkbox (or something similar, I still have to think about it) that allows you to select, beyond the current region (country), also other regions (countries) so you can compare data.

What I would like is:

- if `cs != null` -> I want to get a list of countries (all countries in the Json file)
- if `rs != null` -> I want to get the list of regions of the country to which the rs belongs.

To understand each other better:
[image]

This is what I tried to do.

```
// global variables
cs = null;  // if it is not null, the user has selected this country
csi = null; // country id
rs = null;  // if it is not null, the user has selected this region
rsi = null; // region id
currentCountries = null; // list of all countries
currentRegions = null; // list of regions in the selected country

/**
 * Function that creates line charts only when a country or a region is clicked.
 */
function createLineChart(antigenSelected, yearSelected, countrySelected, countrySelectedId, regionSelected, regionSelectedId) {
   defineLines(antigenSelected, yearSelected, countrySelected, countrySelectedId, regionSelected, regionSelectedId);
}

function defineLines(antigenSelected, yearSelected, countrySelected, countrySelectedId, regionSelected, regionSelectedId) {
   /**
    * To know if the user has clicked on the country or region, check that the selected region belongs to the selected country:
    *   - if it belongs to us -> the user has clicked on the selected region
    *   - if it does not belong to us -> the user has clicked on the selected country.
    * At any moment only one of the two possibilities is assigned (the other is null).
    */
   cs = null;  // if it is not null, the user has selected this country
   csi = null; // country id
   rs = null;  // if it is not null, the user has selected this region
   rsi = null; // region id

   // if the user has selected a region
   if(regionSelectedId != null && countrySelectedId == regionSelectedId.substring(0, 2)) {
      rs = regionSelected;
      rsi = regionSelectedId;
   }
   // if the user has selected a country
   else {
      cs = countrySelected;
      csi = countrySelectedId;
   }

   console.log("countrySelected: " + cs);
   console.log("regionSelected: " + rs);

   /**
    * Load json with countries and regions.
    */
   d3.json("../Project2/data/json/countriesAndRegions.json", function(error, countriesAndRegions) {
      if(error) {
         console.log("*** ERROR LOADING FILES: " + error + " ***");
         throw error;
      }

      countriesAndRegions.forEach(function(c) {
         allCountries.push(c.countryName);
         currentRegions = c.regions;
      });

      currentRegions.forEach(function(r) {
         //console.log(r.regionName);
      });

      console.log(allCountries);
      console.log(currentRegions);

      //var nested = d3.nest()
         // I have to nest data?
         //.object(currentRegions);

   });

}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work. Or rather, it works for `allCountries` but not for `currentRegions`.
How can I solve? Should I use the `nest()` method?

What I want is:

- if `cs != null` -> get all countries
- if `rs != null` -> get all regions of the country to which the `rs` region belongs.

Thanks a lot

---

To simplify, imagine that I have this json file.

```
var users = [
    {
        name: 'Corbin',
        age: 20,
        favoriteFoods: ['ice cream', 'pizza'],
        other: [
            {
                a: 12,
                b: "apple"
            }, 
            {
                a: 15,
                b: "pear"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
        favoriteFoods: ['ice cream', 'skittle'],
        other: [
            {
                a: 0,
                b: "cinnamon"
            }, 
            {
                a: 854,
                b: "ginger"
            }, 
            {
                a: 24,
                b: "salt"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then I have a variable that contains the string `ginger`. How can I get the list `[cinnamon, ginger, salt]`?

And if I have a variable containing the string `Corbin`, how do I get the list `[Corbin, John]`?

Comment: is there problem in accessing json element?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: did you try to access them with index position?

Comment: I don't have the index, just the name of the country or the name of the region.

Comment: follow my answer what i posted below and let me know if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this requirement requires the **`key`** to be fetched based on the value and I've come up with an approach that uses a recursive call (there might be better approaches though).

**Steps (*simplified*):**

1. Loop through an array. Let's call the elements of array as a `row`.
2. Get `row` keys by `Object.keys(row)`
3. Loop through all the keys within the `row`.
4. If `row[key]` is an object, just find the appropriate key/value pair that matches the **`value`** passed (main value - either **cs or rs**) and return the associated `key`.
   I've used `break` statements all over and finally a **array.map()** based on the associated `key`.
5. BUT if `row[key]` is an **Array**, use the recursive call and perform the above steps.

Hope this explains the code. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

```js
var data = [
    {
        "countryName": "Austria",
        "countryID": "AT",
        "countryPopulation": 8451860,
        "regions":[
            {
                "regionName": "Burgenland (AT)",
                "regionID": "AT11",
                "regionPopulation": 286691 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Niederösterreich",
                "regionID": "AT12",
                "regionPopulation": 1618592
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Wien",
                "regionID": "AT13",
                "regionPopulation": 1741246
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Kärnten",
                "regionID": "AT21",
                "regionPopulation": 555473 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Steiermark",
                "regionID": "AT22",
                "regionPopulation": 1210971 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Oberösterreich",
                "regionID": "AT31",
                "regionPopulation": 1418498 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Salzburg",
                "regionID": "AT32",
                "regionPopulation": 531898 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Tirol",
                "regionID": "AT33",
                "regionPopulation": 715888  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Vorarlberg",
                "regionID": "AT34",
                "regionPopulation": 372603 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "countryName": "Belgium",
        "countryID": "BE",
        "countryPopulation": 11161642,
        "regions":[
            {
                "regionName": "Région de Bruxelles-Capitale",
                "regionID": "BE10",
                "regionPopulation": 1174624 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Antwerpen",
                "regionID": "BE21",
                "regionPopulation": 1802309  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Limburg (BE)",
                "regionID": "BE22",
                "regionPopulation": 855963 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Oost-Vlaanderen",
                "regionID": "BE23",
                "regionPopulation": 1465150  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Vlaams-Brabant",
                "regionID": "BE24",
                "regionPopulation": 1103737  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. West-Vlaanderen",
                "regionID": "BE25",
                "regionPopulation": 1177567 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Brabant Wallon",
                "regionID": "BE31",
                "regionPopulation": 389479  
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Hainaut",
                "regionID": "BE32",
                "regionPopulation": 1332489 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Liège",
                "regionID": "BE33",
                "regionPopulation": 1095977
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Luxembourg (BE)",
                "regionID": "BE34",
                "regionPopulation": 278278 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Prov. Namur",
                "regionID": "BE35",
                "regionPopulation": 486069 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "countryName": "Bulgaria",
        "countryID": "BG",
        "countryPopulation": 7284552,
        "regions":[
            {
                "regionName": "Severozapaden",
                "regionID": "BG31",
                "regionPopulation": 823469 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Severen tsentralen",
                "regionID": "BG32",
                "regionPopulation": 844511
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Severoiztochen",
                "regionID": "BG33",
                "regionPopulation": 957460 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Yugoiztochen",
                "regionID": "BG34",
                "regionPopulation": 1067981 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Yugozapaden",
                "regionID": "BG41",
                "regionPopulation": 2128783 
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Yuzhen tsentralen",
                "regionID": "BG42",
                "regionPopulation": 1462348 
            }
        ]
    }
];

var cs = 'Belgium', rs = 'Yuzhen tsentralen';

// cs is not null, get all countries but first find the key
var mainKey = null;

function getKey(array, value) {
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var flag = false, row = array[i], keys = Object.keys(row);
    for(var j=0; j<keys.length; j++) {
      var key = keys[j];
      if(Array.isArray(row[key])) {
        getKey(row[key], value);
      } else if(row[key] === value) { 
        mainKey = key;
        flag = true;
        console.log(array.map(function(d) { return d[mainKey];}));
        break;
      }
    }
    if(flag) {
      break;
    }
  }  
}

if(cs != null) {
  getKey(data, cs);
}
if(rs != null) { 
  getKey(data, rs);
}

/********************
This is what I thought earlier about the requirement, use it if you find it helpful
*************/
/*
// with underscore.js
var row = _.findWhere(data, {countryName: cs});
if(row) { 
  console.log(row["regions"]);
  console.log(row["regions"].map(function(r) { return r["regionName"]; }));
}

// without underscore.js
var index = null;
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { 
  if(data[i]['countryName'] === cs) {
     index = i;
     break;
  }
}
console.log(data[index]["regions"]);
console.log(data[index]["regions"].map(function(r) { return r["regionName"]; }));
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for example I have a json array sample same as your json array:

```
var users = [{name: 'Corbin', age: 20, favoriteFoods: ['ice cream', 'pizza']},
             {name: 'John', age: 25, favoriteFoods: ['ice cream', 'skittle']}];
```

and i have to access the age property of the second user, then:
`users[1].age` will work.

if you have to access the second "favoriteFood" of the first user then you should use:
`users[0].favoriteFoods[2]`.

according to you request i am going to post an another sample code:

Comment: your json looks big only but it is same as i have given to you. as your `"regions"` is alike to `favoriteFoods`

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer doesn't help me. I modified the main message, hoping that my request is clearer..

Comment: check my another sample code in existing answer . hope it will solve out your issue.

Comment: I have no numerical indices, so in your example I couldn't write `date[0]`. What I would like is something like the `data[Name = 'XYZ']`. Moreover, my file is more complex because it contains "objects inside objects", yours is more linear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in this piece of code:

```
regionSelectedId != null && countrySelectedId == regionSelectedId.substring(0, 2)
```

Since `countrySelectedId` will always be `null` when `regionSelectedId` is `null`, that expression will always return false. You just have to modify it into something useful.

Comment: What would be the values of `countrySelectedId`and `regionSelectedId` that you are using?

Comment: Honestly, I thought that those values in the future could be used to derive the list of countries/regions that interests me. For the moment those variables are not used.